# Migrating from Firebase JS SDK (Web) to react-native-firebase for offline storage

Tags: react-native, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I have been using Firebase Web SDK for my react-native app (I am using FIRESTORE to store the data). Up to this point, I have had no problems. It all works smoothly. But now I want to add some kind of offline storage mechanism to my app so that I could still offer some functionality or display some content that was cached from the last connected session even if my users are offline. After some investigation, I have the impression that [react-native-firebase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-firebase) is the preferred way to go. Now I have some questions and I like to get some advice from the experienced.

- Is react-native-firebase the only option to go? I have quickly read about [AsyncStorage](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage) and it is just a key-value storage. Considering the simplest thing I want to do is page through a list of firestore documents, this kind of storage seems not to be suitable to do this offline. Like If I wanted to do this with AsyncStorage I would have to put all the content (maybe hundreds of documents) I get from the firestore backend, persist them as a single string value, fetch them back, parse them, page them etc. And write custom logic& methods for all these.
- If I was to use react-native-firebase, just enabling the offline storage -I assume- takes care of this for you and you don't have to write any custom logic for offline storage usage. I assume the data that has persisted for offline usage has the same structure as it does in firestore database. I feel like If I use anything other than react-native-firebase, I would have to handle all the custom logic for persisting, reading and rendering the data offline myself. Is that right?
- The biggest concern I have is the amount of code refactoring that might be required. I have many lines of code and so many `.get().then()` like lines where I get and render the data from firestore. In the documentation of react-native-firebase it says:

> ...aims to mirror the official Firebase Web SDK as closely as
>   possible.

I am not sure to what extent this is true. I have checked the react-native-firebase's firestore module's [reference documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/firestore/reference/firestore) but I just can't tell how many of these querying methods are actually supported.

So, the way to go is react-native-firebase's way? Would it take a heavy toll on me trying to refactor the existing code? Any similar experience do you have?
I would appreciate any help.

Thanks a lot...

Comment: You're asking us to recommend using a certain technology, which is off topic on Stack Overflow. That said, since react-native-firebase is the recommended solution and you have no experience indicating that it won't work, how about simply giving it a try? If you encounter problems while converting your app, it'll be a lot easier (and more likely on topic) for us to help.

Comment: Hi Puf. Thanks for the comment. I was asking for options based on the experiences of the people which does not necessarily mean recommendation. And that is only part of my question. But hey.. Thanks anyway..

Answer (score 2):

Maintainer of the react-native-firebase library here.

> ...aims to mirror the official Firebase Web SDK as closely as possible.

This is a minor disclaimer as there are some differences between the two, mainly down to how certain things have to be implemented with React Native.

For example, `enablePersistence` does not exist on RNFB. Instead, persistence is enabled by default and can be toggled off (or on) via `settings()`.

> Is react-native-firebase the only option to go? I have quickly read about AsyncStorage and it is just a key-value storage. Considering the simplest thing I want to do is page through a list of firestore documents, this kind of storage seems not to be suitable to do this offline. Like If I wanted to do this with AsyncStorage I would have to put all the content (maybe hundreds of documents) I get from the firestore backend, persist them as a single string value, fetch them back, parse them, page them etc. And write custom logic& methods for all these.

This is technically possible, however there are downsides to this as you have mentioned. With Firestore, when the device goes offline (quite common on apps) and you attempt a read/write it'll read/update your local cache, which will still trigger event listeners. When the app goes back online, it'll automatically re-sync with the server for you.

> If I was to use react-native-firebase, just enabling the offline storage -I assume- takes care of this for you and you don't have to write any custom logic for offline storage usage. I assume the data that has persisted for offline usage has the same structure as it does in firestore database. I feel like If I use anything other than react-native-firebase, I would have to handle all the custom logic for persisting, reading and rendering the data offline myself. Is that right?

This is all handled for you. We wrap around the native Firebase SDKs so expect the same level of consistency if you were developing a native Android/iOS app if not using React Native.

> The biggest concern I have is the amount of code refactoring that might be required. I have many lines of code and so many .get().then() like lines where I get and render the data from firestore.

Generally everything is the same apart from a few minor methods for reasons mentioned above.

> So, the way to go is react-native-firebase's way? Would it take a heavy toll on me trying to refactor the existing code? Any similar experience do you have? I would appreciate any help.

I'd recommend anyone developing with React Native & Firebase to use RNFB. It provides a lot of extra functionality the Web SDK cannot provide with React Native. Apart from a more cumbersome setup & changing imports, it should work very much the same.

Comment: Hello Elliot, thanks for the reply. It has cleared and confirmed some doubts for me. Thanks for that! Do you think using react-native-firebase could also help with this infamous problem for the part that is related to firebase/firestore? -> https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12981#issuecomment-292947299

Comment: I *think* so... I suspect the Web SDK uses timers whereas we use the React Native event listeners to send updates from JS <-> Native. What exact use case with the Web SDK causes the timers warning?

Comment: Hello Elliot. I am not sure but I feel like most of the promises are creating these warnings.

Comment: I'd imagine the Web SDK uses long timers then as generally functionality which works fine on the web, however can probably lead to memory leaks and whatnot on React Native. We use events like mentioned above so there shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @ElliotHesp was looking at using react native web sdk together with RNFB as there are existing code already using JS sdk for firebase. Is that possible?

Comment: @HongZhou technically yes, however remember that if you say used Authentication on RNFB Firestore on JS SDK, then the Firestore side of things won't know about the user being authenticated.